# iPhone 5 storyboard still shows padding when running on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, iphone-5, autoresize

[image]I have made a new app with storyboard, where the storyboard is currently just for iPhone 5. But the issue is, when I run this on iPhone 5 device/simulator, it shows padding at the top and bottom of the screen as if an iPhone 4 application is being run. Please see the screenshot I have attached. And help where did I go wrong.

[image]

EDIT : Actually its still not working. In iOS 8 its coming fullscreen but in iOS 7 for some reason the black padding is coming. PLease hellpppp.

Comment: Have you add launch images for 4 inch device?

Comment: Yes I did. Yet it is coming this way.

Comment: Can you post your code where you create the `UIWindow` which created in the App delegate.

Comment: Hi,Added the screenshot - its not coded. Its just a UIWindow declaration in AppDelegate.h and then the Main.storyboard added to Plist - Main storyboard file base name.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Version :Xcode 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - I got the issue.Apparently, in xcode 6, when Launchscreen.xib is given, it does not work for ios 7 and it works perfectly normal for ios8.

Previous answer - The issue was, in Xcode 6.0, the new project generates a LaunchScreen.xib file, but apparently you manually have to go to the General settings for the target and select the launch screen File options from the drop down. This solves the issues. :) 
 [image]